# About extension methods

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, extension-methods

Shall I always need to throw `ArgumentNullException` when an extension method is called on null? (Extension methods in `Enumerable` throw `ArgumentNullException`.) I would like to have clarification on this. If the answer is both "Yes" and "No" please present both the cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to throw it if the argument is `null` and you don't support that condition. If that isn't a problem, there's no need to throw the exception. One might expect in *most* cases that a null argument for the `this` argument would be an unsupportable condition, but by no means is that *always* the case.

The need for throwing this exception (and for null checking) is no different in extension methods than in traditional methods.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this kinds of methods defined often as extension methods:

```
public static bool IsNull(this object item)
{
    return item == null;
}
```

and used like:

```
object o = null;
if (o.IsNull())
  return;
```

So, in this special case, it makes no sense to throw if the argument is null. Extension methods are not different from any other methods, just the syntax is fancier.